# Issue with disappearing images on click event (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am supposed to build a store for a a javascript assignment.  The store has three items and a counter which tallies the total of the items.  Each item is updated through a click event which changes the value based on a data attribute defined in the html.  It then saves this to cookies and allows us to use what was stored when we get to a checkout page.  The cookies store and the totals update, but unfortunately, each time the click event occurs, the image disappears.  I have been scouring the code and I cannot see why this is happening.  Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jeans-line").text(Cookies.get("jeans") || 0)
  $("#jeanJacket-line").text(Cookies.get("jeanJacket") || 0)
  $("#belt-line").text(Cookies.get("belt") || 0)
  $("#total").text(Cookies.get("total") || 0)
  //The DOM will be changed to the key value of each cookie or 0

  $('.item').click(function() {
    itemTotal = parseInt($(this).text())
    oneMore = itemTotal + ($(this).data('cost'))
    $(this).text(oneMore)
    Cookies.set($(this).data('name'), oneMore)
    setTotal()
  });

  // //updating the total cost of the pseudo-items in shopping

  function setTotal() {
    var jeans = parseInt(Cookies.get("jeans"))
    var jeanJacket = parseInt(Cookies.get("jeanJacket"))
    var belt = parseInt(Cookies.get("belt"))

    Cookies.set("total", (jeans + jeanJacket + belt) || 0)
    $("#total").text(Cookies.get("total") || 0)
  };

  //Enter data and close the modal
  var modal = $("#modal-box")
  var email_input;

  $(".email-submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    email_input = $("#email-val").val()
    console.log(email_input)
    var checkEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (checkEmail.test(email_input)) {
      alert("This is a good email!")
      Cookies.set("email", email_input)
      modal.css("display", "none")
    } else {
      alert("This is not a valid email address!")
    }
  });

  //closes the model with close click event
  $(".close").click(function() {
    modal.css("display", "none");
  });

}) //closes document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="item" data-cost="200" data-name="jeans">
      <img id="jeansIMG" src="images/jeans.jpg">
      <h2 class="item" id="jeans-line"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="item" data-cost="300" data-name="jeanJacket">
      <img id="jeanJacketIMG" src="images/jean_jacket.jpg">
      <h2 class="item" id="jeanJacket-line"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="item" data-cost="50" data-name="belt">
      <img id="beltIMG" src="images/belt.jpg">
      <h2 class="item" id="belt-line"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- closes the bootstrap row -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="shoppingCart" src="images/shopping_cart.jpg">
    <h2 class="totalTitle">The total for these pseudo-products is:</h2>
    <h2 id="total"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: never dump complete code, narrow down the problem and then  add only relevant code,

Comment: I updated it and removed the CSS, as well as the HTML opening/closing and the modal, which works fine.

Comment: Actually, in order to make a [mcve], you'll probably need your CSS and HTML in order to recreate your problem.

Comment: `$(this).text(oneMore)` overwrites the entire contents of the `.item` div, including the img element. (As an aside, a coding style note: in Javascript semicolons at the end of lines *are* (mostly) optional, but please make a deliberate choice to either use them or not, don't just sprinkle them randomly about.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why images are getting remove is because of this code:

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    itemTotal = parseInt($(this).text())
    oneMore = itemTotal + ($(this).data('cost'))
    $(this).text(oneMore) // <-- this overrides everything inside div.item
    Cookies.set($(this).data('name'), oneMore)
    setTotal() 
});
```

Seeing your overall code, I'd suggest to change inner `item` class to something else (eg. `item-total`) so it won't be conflicting with the outer `item` class. After that adjust the javascript code:

```
$('.item').click(function() {
  itemTotal = parseInt($(this).text())
  oneMore = itemTotal + ($(this).data('cost'))
  $('.item-total', this).text(oneMore) // <!-- change text in item-total
  Cookies.set($(this).data('name'), oneMore)
  setTotal()
});
```

You may also want to modify the `setTotal` to add default value `|| 0` so that it will calculate the total properly even if there is one or more items left unclicked:

```
function setTotal() {
 var jeans = parseInt(Cookies.get("jeans") || 0)
 var jeanJacket = parseInt(Cookies.get("jeanJacket") || 0)
 var belt = parseInt(Cookies.get("belt") || 0)

 Cookies.set("total", (jeans + jeanJacket + belt) || 0)
 $("#total").text(Cookies.get("total") || 0)
};
```

You can check the simplified demo in https://jsfiddle.net/nm5dL9h1/

Comment: Ah yes, you are totally correct!  I was staring at this for over an hour.  It's the simple things that can hurt you the most.  Thanks for the insight.